# Завтра экзамен. Просьба к языковедам-профессионалам: помогите с синтаксическим разбором предложения:

Tags: синтаксис

Завтра экзамен. Просьба к языковедам-профессионалам: помогите с синтаксическим разбором предложения:                                                              Презирать суд людей нетрудно, презирать суд собственный - невозможно. Это сложное предложение, где подлежащее - презирать, а нетрудно и невозможно - сказуемые. Или это односост., инфинитивное, простое предл. с однор сказуемыми

Answer (score 3):

```
  Это сложное предложение, где подлежащее - презирать, а нетрудно
   и     невозможно - сказуемые?
```

Именно так, бессоюзное сложное предложение с инфинитивами в роли подлежащих.

А вот если бы было:
Нетрудно  презирать суд людей,невозможно презирать суд собственный.-

тогда были бы безличные простые предложения в составе бессоюзного сложного.